# Laravel sortby after select specific option

Tags: laravel

I would like to add a select field in my application with the option of choosing to sort products by date of addition or price. After selecting a specific option, e.g. sort by price, products returned from the cheapest are returned. I know how to sort products but I do not know how to do it to show sorted products after selecting a specific option, e.g. sort by price. My code :

web.php

```
Route::get('/{category}', 'ProductController@index');
```

ProductController:

```
public function index()
    {          
        $products= Product::latest()->get();
        return view('category')->with('products', $products);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view you could use a form like this to get wich category the user wants to filter:

```html
<form method="get" action="{{route('product.index')}}">
@csrf
 <select name="category">
  <option value="price">Price</option>
  <option value="date">Date</option>
 </select>
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

And in your controller you can filter the collection using the selected option:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {          
        $products= Product::all()->sortBy($request->category);
        return view('category')->with('products', $products);
    }
```